# Como rodar arquivos php no navegador usando VS Code?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Estou fazendo um site em php com o VS Code mas não estou conseguindo testar o site no navegador. Já até instalei a extensão "PHP Server" para VS Code mas continua sem funcionar. Algúem pode me ajudar com isto? Valeu pela força.

Answer (score 2):

O PHP a partir da versão 5.4 disponibiliza um servidor embutido para desenvolvimento, para utilizar abra um terminal/prompt de comando no diretório do seu projeto e digite:

php -S localhost:8000

Acesse pelo navegador através de http://localhost:8000

Fonte: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: Incrível, me deparei com essa solução e cara, eu nem imaginava que isso era possível! Solução perfeita! Por mais que possa não ser bem o que @Alison gostaria, isso ajudaria muitas pessoas que não querem criar dependência em servidores apache executáveis.

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de rodar pelo VSCODE, pode também utilizar o Xampp.

Basicamente, o Xampp cria um servidor Apache para rodar seus scripts. É bastante simples de instalar. Após a instalação basta abrir e iniciar o servidor clicando em start no módulo do Apache.
Para rodar os scripts, basta deixá-los na pasta htdocs, junto de onde você decidir instalar o Xampp e então acessá-los pelo seu localhost.

Pode encontrá-lo neste link: https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/index.html